# Animate image on different screen in kivy

Tags: python, animation, kivy

I am trying to automatically animate an Image that is placed in another class when the caroussel is switched. With the button it works without problems but not automatically. I tried different things with "id" but I am relatively new to this so maybe there is a general mistake.
Usually there are 2 Screens in the screenmanager and the second screen leads to the caroussel. Due to simplicity I let the first screen out.
Also I am planning to play a movie in Screen1 and want to stop it when the user switches to Screen2. 
I think the main question is how can I control functions in a different class.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.image import Image

Builder.load_string('''

#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<Screen1>:
    name: "screen1"
    Image:
        id: image1
        source: './img/somearrowup.png'
        pos: 205, 145
    Label:
        text: 'Screen down'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .85,.15                  
        Button:
            text: 'Anim1'
            on_release: root.anim1()

<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    Image:
        id: image2
        source: 'somearrowdown.png'
        pos: 205, 55
    Label:
        text: 'Screen Up'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .85,.15
        Button:
            text: 'Anim2'
            on_release: root.anim2()

<Carou>:
    Screen:
        Carousel:
            id: carousel
            on_index: root.on_index(*args)
            direction: 'top'
            Screen1:
            Screen2:

''')

class Screen1(Screen):    
    def anim1(self):
        self.ids.image1.pos = 205, 155
        animation = Animation(pos=(205, 145),t='out_elastic')
        animation.start(self.ids.image1)

class Screen2(Screen):
    def anim2(self):
        self.ids.image2.pos = 205, 55
        animation = Animation(pos=(205, 45),t='out_elastic')
        animation.start(self.ids.image2)

class Carou(BoxLayout):    
    def on_index(self, instance, value):
        if instance.current_slide.name == 'screen2':
            print ("here an animation in Screen2")
            screen = Screen2()  #doesn't work
            screen.anim2()      #doesn't work
        else:
            print ("here an animation in Screen1")
            #...

class StartMenu(App):        
    def build(self):        
        sm = ScreenManager()        
        screen = Screen()        
        screen.add_widget(Carou())
        screen.name = 'carousel'
        sm.add_widget(screen)

        return sm
```

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in your `on_index()` method, you are creating a new `Screen2` and calling its `anim2()` method. What you really want is to call the `anim2()` method in the `Screen2`  instance that is displayed in your `Carousel`. To do this, replace:

```
screen = Screen2()
```

with:

```
screen = instance.current_slide
```